# Why bash can not run .out file?

Tags: linux, bash

Use `gcc a.c` can get the output binary `a.out`.

**a.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

*1. Under bash shell next is ok.*

```
$ file a.out
a.out: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=6107be037f932892b69677f69b90a1d71b94e9e4, not stripped
$ ./a.out
Hello world!
```

*2. Under bash shell next is not ok.*

```
$ bash a.out
a.out: a.out: cannot execute binary file
```

**My question:**

What's difference for above two?

`bash xxx` may can just execute something like `a.sh`, this maybe the answer, but what `$ ./a.out` do when I do it in bash shell, seems it also run in bash? Difference of them? Please help me to understand, thanks.

Comment: `bash xxx` treats `xxx` as a bash script. It's not for arbitrary commands; **only** bash code can be included in a file invoked that way, just as you can only have valid Python code in a file you invoke with `python foo.py`.

Comment: `./a.out` calls an `execv`-family function, letting the operating system itself decide how to treat it. Typically it uses `ld.so`, if what you have is an executable binary, though on Linux your various `binfmt` kernel modules can get involved.

Comment: ...that said, I'm something like 95% sure we have this question already answered over on [unix.se] -- and unless its answer changes how you engage in the practice of software development (see the "practical" element of the fourth bullet point in https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), I'm not sure it's topical here.

Comment: So, the `$` is currently a bash, and the bash source code behave as follows: find it not have a interpreter, so then call `execve` to execute the `a.out`?

Comment: No, bash doesn't look at whether there's an interpreter at all -- it directly hands it over to the OS, and the OS kernel looks for a shebang (the `#!` line) to see if there's an interpreter, or for ELF or DWARF magic (or other formats as appropriate -- `binfmt_misc` can be used to let Linux handle arbitrary other file formats, ie. Java jars) to flag it as a binary.

Comment: ...so, if you use bash to start a bash script, it's not the same copy of bash you already have running interpreting that script -- the shell performs a syscall asking the kernel to invoke the file as an executable, the kernel looks at it and decides that it's a script, and starts a whole new/different copy of bash (or whatever interpreter is indicated by the shebang) to interpret it.

Comment: Yeah, this make me clear about that, thanks.